# Data Mismatch Error Access query

Tags: ms-access

I am trying to get the target data for a specific period using `left join` and `between` function as in code below. However I get Data mismatch error when I run the code and when I remove the `betwwen` code the query runs properly.

Tried playing around with the brackets, no luck till now.

```
FROM Qry_Status 
LEFT JOIN Qry_Target ON (Qry_Status.[Dept Code] = Qry_Target.[Dept Code]) 
And (iif(IsDate(Qry_Status.sDate),Qry_Status.sDate Between ([Qry_Target].[From_Date]) 
And ([Qry_Target].[To_Date])))
```

Comment: It's not clear what the logic is supposed to be in this code.  `x BETWEEN y AND z` sounds like it would be in a `WHERE` clause, and logically should result in a boolean.  But you're trying to use it as a date?

Comment: There are 2 queries for e.g. one query has sDate, Ename, Ecode, Dept Code and another has Dept Code, Target, From_date, To_Date what I am trying to acheive is "Ename, Ecode, Dept Code, Target (where sDate is between From_date and To_Date". So the target should be for the date range between from and to date. Hope this helps. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
FROM Qry_Status 
LEFT JOIN Qry_Target ON (Qry_Status.[Dept Code] = Qry_Target.[Dept Code]) 
And (iif(IsDate(Qry_Status.sDate),Qry_Status.sDate Between Qry_Target.[From_Date] 
And Qry_Target.[To_Date]), Qry_Status.sDate LIKE "*")
```